# Where is the request model in this vendor WSDL?

Tags: wcf

I'm attempting to create user accounts for a vendor tool in batches. I asked the vendor how to turn on the MEX for the endpoint for creating a single account and I adjusted the config file accordingly.

I was able to create a service reference, but all I have in Visual Studio is a client and two interfaces. I can't tell how to create a request. The client has an InvokeService method, but it just takes an object.

I replicated the vendors class structure in my code, but then the service didn't like my type. So, I updated the classes to use the vendor's original namespace, but the service still didn't like it.

```
Type 'life.businessService.baseBusinessDataModel.BusinessRequest' with data contract name 'BusinessRequest:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/life.businessService.baseBusinessDataModel' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

Here's the WSDL from the service. I'm not very strong in WCF, so I'm hoping for some guidance. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ClientWcfBusinessFacadeService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="NetNamedPipeBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <msb:BinaryEncoding xmlns:msb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/mspolicy/netbinary1">
        </msb:BinaryEncoding>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing>
        </wsaw:UsingAddressing>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="NetTcpBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <msb:BinaryEncoding xmlns:msb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/mspolicy/netbinary1">
        </msb:BinaryEncoding>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing>
        </wsaw:UsingAddressing>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/life.common.serviceCommon" />
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IWcfBusinessFacade_InvokeService_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:InvokeService" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IWcfBusinessFacade_InvokeService_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:InvokeServiceResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IWcfBusinessFacade_InvokeService_ServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage">
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/life.common.serviceCommon" name="detail" element="q1:ServiceFault" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IWcfBusinessFacade">
    <wsdl:operation name="InvokeService">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWcfBusinessFacade/InvokeService" message="tns:IWcfBusinessFacade_InvokeService_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWcfBusinessFacade/InvokeServiceResponse" message="tns:IWcfBusinessFacade_InvokeService_OutputMessage" />
      <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IWcfBusinessFacade/InvokeServiceServiceFaultFault" name="ServiceFaultFault" message="tns:IWcfBusinessFacade_InvokeService_ServiceFaultFault_FaultMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade" type="tns:IWcfBusinessFacade">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#NetNamedPipeBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade_policy">
    </wsp:PolicyReference>
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/named-pipe" />
    <wsdl:operation name="InvokeService">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IWcfBusinessFacade/InvokeService" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="ServiceFaultFault">
        <soap12:fault use="literal" name="ServiceFaultFault" namespace="" />
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="NetTcpBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade" type="tns:IWcfBusinessFacade">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#NetTcpBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade_policy">
    </wsp:PolicyReference>
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/tcp" />
    <wsdl:operation name="InvokeService">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IWcfBusinessFacade/InvokeService" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="ServiceFaultFault">
        <soap12:fault use="literal" name="ServiceFaultFault" namespace="" />
        <soap12:fault use="literal" name="ServiceFaultFault" namespace="" />
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ClientWcfBusinessFacadeService">
    <wsdl:port name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade" binding="tns:NetNamedPipeBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade">
      <soap12:address location="net.pipe://localhost/WcfBusinessFacadeService" />
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>net.pipe://localhost/WcfBusinessFacadeService</wsa10:Address>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="NetTcpBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade" binding="tns:NetTcpBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade">
      <soap12:address location="net.tcp://localhost:8086/WcfBusinessFacadeService" />
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>net.tcp://localhost:8086/WcfBusinessFacadeService</wsa10:Address>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="NetTcpBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade1" binding="tns:NetTcpBinding_IWcfBusinessFacade">
      <soap12:address location="net.tcp://localhost:10000/WcfBusinessFacadeService" />
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>net.tcp://localhost:10000/WcfBusinessFacadeService</wsa10:Address>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the input message of the InvokeService method, you need to pass the object defined in tns:InvokeService. It will be a type in namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports, but is not explicitly exposed in this WSDL; it is coming from another namespace.  You may ask the vendor for the schema XSD or assembly from which this WSDL is expecting to import types below since no absolute or even relative schemaLocation attribute is included

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/life.common.serviceCommon" />
```

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks!